# Parametric estimation of the portfolio var

Tags: portfolio

I have a portfolio that consists of multiple positions. I have historical prices for these positions. So I can estimate the var of the portfolio:

```
portfolio_var = sqrt(Weights_T x Returns_Covariance x Weights) * z
```

Then, I can estimate component VAR. Which will show how each position contributed to the portfolio var:

```
component_var = portfolio_var x Weights
```

This approach is well documented and explained.

Now, let's imagine I want to group positions, i.e. positions are opened by different funds, and I am looking to estimate each fund's var instead of each position's var.

How do I approach this problem?
I considered isolating positions, calculating their isolated var, and then moving to the fund vars. Still, the problem is that the correlations are given at the position level...

Comment: How does this relate to personal finance for you?

Comment: I am trying to understand how to manage portfolio risks